# String from master page displayed on content page

Tags: asp.net, string, master-pages

I'm trying to display a string on my content page which is set in the master page but i'm getting the error message: **'compid' is not a member of 'ASP.test_master'**

Here's my master page code:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" debug="true"  %>
<script runat="server">
    Dim compid As String = "test"
</script>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="CPHLoginButton" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

And my content page code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="test.master" %>
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/test.master" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="CPHLoginButton" runat="server">
    <%= Master.compid %>
</asp:Content>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably becuase of default access modifier. Your problem can be solved by making compid public somethign like this `Public compid As String = "test"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following:

```
<%= (Me.Master as test).compid %>
```